# I want read content of a list tag under the ul tag. But I'm not able to read using the below code.

Tags: java, selenium

URL: https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A1571271031%2Cn%3A%211571272031%2Cn%3A1968024031%2Cn%3A1968093031%2Cp_n_pct-off-with-tax%3A70-%2Cp_98%3A10440597031&page=2&bbn=1968093031&ie=UTF8&qid=1501915937&lo=apparel

Code is listed as Fallows:

```
try{

    //WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#atfResults > ul"));
    WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.id("s-results-list-atf"));
    System.out.println(e1);

    List<WebElement> links = e1.findElements(By.cssSelector("#atfResults > ul"));;
    for (int i = 1; i < links.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any one get solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Are you sure you don't over complicate things by trying to scrape amazon search results? I'd expect using their API would be way easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the content of a list tag (Item names) under the ul tag from the `url` "https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A1571271031%2Cn%3A%211571272031%2Cn%3A1968024031%2Cn%3A1968093031%2Cp_n_pct-off-with-tax%3A70-%2Cp_98%3A10440597031&page=2&bbn=1968093031&ie=UTF8&qid=1501915937&lo=apparel", you can use the following code block:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Q45519900_amazon_list 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=n%3A1571271031%2Cn%3A%211571272031%2Cn%3A1968024031%2Cn%3A1968093031%2Cp_n_pct-off-with-tax%3A70-%2Cp_98%3A10440597031&page=2&bbn=1968093031&ie=UTF8&qid=1501915937&lo=apparel");
        List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']/li[starts-with(@id, 'result_')]/div/div[@class='a-row a-spacing-none']/div/a/h2"));
        System.out.println("Total items : "+element.size());
        for (WebElement my_element:element)
        {
        String title = my_element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        System.out.println("Item name is : "+title);
        }

    }

}
```

The output on the console is:

```
Total items : 48
Item name is : GlobalRang Men's Cotton Formal Shirt
Item name is : Rapphael Men's Full sleeve Casual Shirt
Item name is : Feed Up Pack of 4 Men's Pocket Shirts
Item name is : Rapphael Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Arihant Men's Solid Formal Shirt
Item name is : United Colors of Benetton Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Mossimo Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Urban Nomad Orange Cotton Formal Shirt
Item name is : Men's Cotton Shirt
Item name is : Slub Mens Shirt
Item name is : United Colors of Benetton Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Rapphael Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Arihant Men's Full Sleeves Regular fit Formal Shirt
Item name is : Arihant Men's Formal Shirt
Item name is : Rapphael Charcoal Grey &amp; Blue color Casual Shirt for men
Item name is : Urban Nomad Yellow Cotton Formal Shirt
Item name is : GlobalRang Men's Cotton Casual Royal Blue Stand Collar Shirt
Item name is : SHADE 45 Men's Premium designed Cotton Full Sleeve Slim fit Orange color Plain…
Item name is : Basics Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : People Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Dennison Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : IZOD Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Deezeno Men's Cotton Shirt
Item name is : Easies Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Dennison Men's Formal Shirt
Item name is : Slub Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Scott International Men's Premium Cotton Blend Pullover Hoodie Sweatshirt With Zip…
Item name is : Rapphael Men's Full sleeve Casual Shirt
Item name is : United Colors of Benetton Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Dennison Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Arihant Men's Full Sleeves Regular Fit Striped Poly Cotton Formal Shirt
Item name is : GHPC Men's 100%Cotton Slim Fit Full Sleeves Printed Casual Shirt
Item name is : Basics Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Rapphael Green &amp; Black Color Casual Shirt for men
Item name is : Urban Nomad Yellow Cotton Formal Shirt
Item name is : Arihant Men's Formal Shirt
Item name is : Trendy Trotters Pink Fullsleeves Shirt
Item name is : Arihant Men's Full Sleeves Regular fit Formal Shirt
Item name is : Dennison Men's Formal Shirt
Item name is : IZOD Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Dennison Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : GHPC Men's 100%Cotton Slim Fit Full Sleeves Striped Casual Shirt
Item name is : Stylox Bull Printed White Shirt [007
Item name is : Deezeno Men's Cotton Shirt
Item name is : Dennison Men's Formal Shirt
Item name is : People Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : United Colors of Benetton Men's Casual Shirt
Item name is : Rapphael Orange color Casual Shirt for men
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Still I'm not getting the product list. I have fallowed the above code and written into my script but still i haven't found the product list. Its giving null on below line of code.           WebElement all_element = driver.findElement(By.id("s-results-list-atf"));

Comment: Your output is the exactly same which I'm looking for but the above code is not working at my end. Still need help.

Comment: That line was part of the code which you provided. Check my updated Answer.

Comment: Hello, I implemented the updated line of code but still I'm getting null value on the same line and test getting failed.

Comment: Check out my last update and let me know the status.

Comment: Dear friend, Is it really working at your end? Because in my system its giving me java.lang.NullPointerException on the mentioned line. Is there any specific configuration required? I have tried with wait command but its not working. Little more effort will really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @surajsharma The line you mentioned was from your own code which was of no use. I have removed that line from my updated Answer. Simply copy my code & try to execute. If it still fails, update the question with your current code & the exact error stack trace. I will surely help you out.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, Now I got the output. The above code is working perfectly fine. Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: @surajsharma Glad to be able to help you !!!

Comment: Just wanted to understand "when I'm trying this code to execute in testng class under @test annotation then I'm getting null in the list<WebElement>  but same code is working in main method when I'm executing in separate class. Please let me know if you help me in that"

Comment: @surajsharma Apparently it shouldn't. Feel free to raise a new Question with your new requirement we will be glad to help you out.